# First time using mySqli keep getting a 500 error with my php. I think it is trying to return result as a boolean value instead of a table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Like the title says I think it is due to the fact that my code is trying to return a boolean value instead of populating an array of values and I can't seem to change it otherwise. I'm sure this is just a stupid mistake, but I was wondering if anyone can give me any insight as to how to fix this. I can't turn on error reporting with the host I am using, so I am left sort of at a loss for how to move forward.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$host = "***********";
$port = "****";
$dbName = "*********";
$user = "************";
$pass = "************";

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $dbName, $port);

//Variables with defaults
$limit = isset($_REQUEST['limit']) ? $_REQUEST['limit'] : 100;

//Form variables
$minLong = $_REQUEST['minLong'];
$maxLong = $_REQUEST['maxLong'];
$minLat = $_REQUEST['minLat'];
$maxLat = $_REQUEST['maxLat'];
$type = $_REQUEST['type'];

$query = "
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `caches`
WHERE
  `longitude` > ?
  AND
  `longitude` < ?
  AND
  `latitude` > ?
  AND
  `latitude` < ?
LIMIT
  ?";

$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init($mysqli);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param('ddddi', $minLong, $maxLong, $minLat, $maxLat,     $limit);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

$caches = $result->fetch_assoc(); //This is where it is warning me about the boolean result
echo json_encode($caches);
```

Comment: I don't think you can populate LIMIT in that way. (It's also fairly meaningless in the absence of an ORDER BY clause). Prepared statements are great - and vital in production - but in development, I like to use the conventional approach, and echo the query so I can see what MySQL sees.

Comment: your `where` clauses seems to be fighting against each other. *most confusing*

Comment: @Fred-ii- unless I'm missing something they are just doing a between without a between.

Comment: @Augwa it would make more sense using `BETWEEN`, for sure.

Comment: Strawbery is correct and also remove $limit from bind_param or user ORDER BY CLAUSE also. Fred ii is also correct.

Comment: You should be able to turn on error reporting at script level by adding these two lines to the beginning of your script ... error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Comment: check for errors on execute also http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  and for example: `if(!$statement->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$mysqli->error, E_USER_WARNING);}`

Comment: I'll give these suggestions a shot and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Also, are you sure your Form variables are double and integer? Try using $minLong = floatval($_REQUEST['minLong']) on the doubles and $type = intval($_REQUEST['type']) on the integer.

Comment: Instead of guessing, check your web server's error log for the meaning of the 500 error. Also, set *mysqli* to throw exceptions by putting this at the top of your script ~ `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. You might also want to add `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`